# IIS Reverse Proxy is redirecting instead

Tags: iis, server, reverse-proxy, iis-10, bitbucket-server

I am trying to install Atlassian Bitbucket (server edition) on my server and have been struggling with the reverse proxy configuration.

Symptoms:
I'm able to configure the reverse proxy for Bitbucket. I'm just entering the server's name along with the port (bitbucketserver.com:7990) in IIS'reverse proxy configuration window and it seems to work fine, except that it rewrites the URL as well. For example, if my domain is example.com and I've configured reverse proxy for the domain, it *redirects* the browser window to bitbucketserver.com instead of showing the application through the URL *example.com*. Screenshot for reference:

[image]

However, the application seems to be working fine (I'm using IIS 10).

Here's my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://bitbucketserver.com:7990/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have also tried replacing the computer name (bitbucketserver.com) with the IP address of the server, still no luck. I've spent a couple of hours looking for a solution, but no luck. There are other applications running through reverse proxy from the same IIS server, including Atlassian Confluence, which are working without any issues whatsoever. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-set-up-microsoft-iis-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-bitbucket-server-979412589.html Atlassian allows you to leave feedback on its steps, and you can also ask in its community.

Comment: Thnak you, I will do that.